# Traer id con un botón a un formulario en la misma página y luego guardar desde el formulario a la base de datos

Tags: php

Mi consulta acá abajo

```
 <?php 
    session_start();
    include "./php/conexion.php";
    
    
    $traerplanes = $conexion-> query("select * from planes")or die ($conexion->error);
    ?>
```

Acá abajo escribo los datos del Select, que lo que trae es la información de los planes de cada suscripción y es donde está el primer botón "pagar"

```
<?php 
        while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($traerplanes)){
        ?>
                <div class="col-md-5 order-details" style="width:380px">
                        <div class="section-title text-center">
                        </div>
                        <div class="order-summary">
                            <div class="order-col">
                                <div><strong>DESCRIPCIÓN</strong></div>
                                <div><strong>TOTAL</strong></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-products">
                                <div class="order-col">
                                    <div style="text-align:justify; font-size:12px"><?php echo $fila['descripcion'];?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>$<?php echo $fila['precio'];?></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="order-col">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-col">
                                <div><strong>TOTAL</strong></div>
                                <div><strong class="order-total" style="color:#069;">$<?php echo $fila['precio'];?></strong></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="text-align:center;">
                            <label>
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <a href="insertarpago.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id_plan']; ?>" class="primary-btn order-submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registropago">Pagar</a>
        
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Acá arriba se observa el botón pagar donde referencio al archivo insertarpago.php que es donde está la consulta del insert y le paso el id_plan de la suscripcion que lo obtengo del select de arriba.

---

Ahora acá tengo el formulario que es un modal que se abre en la misma página cuando el usuario da click al botón pagar de arriba

```
<!-- Modal Registrar pago -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="registropago" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registropago" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <form action="./php/insertarpago.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="registropago">Pagar Plan</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre del titular de la cuenta de donde pagó" id="nombre" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
                <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="apellido del titular de la cuenta de donde pagó" id="apellido" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="documento">Documento</label>
                <input type="text" name="documento" placeholder="cédula, rif o pasaporte del titular de la cuenta" id="documento" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="banco">Banco</label>
                <input type="text" name="banco" placeholder="nombre del banco desde donde pagó" id="banco" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="numero_cuenta">Número de cuenta</label>
                <input type="number" name="numero_cuenta" placeholder="número de cuenta desde donde pagó" id="numero_cuenta" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="referencia">Referencia</label>
                <input type="number" name="referencia" placeholder="número de referencia de la transferencia" id="referencia" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="monto">Monto</label>
                <input type="number" name="monto" placeholder="monto de la transferencia en Bs.S" id="monto" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="capture_pago">Capture de pago (Opcional)</label>
                <input type="file" name="capture_pago" id="capture_pago" class="form-control">

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Pago</button>
          </div>    
      </form> 
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Bien en este formulario es donde se termina de registrar el pago y en donde debería pasar el id_plan de la suscripción.

Comment: Si te entendí bien ¿Primero quieres que al abrir la pagina o al iniciar la sección de la pagina lleguen 3 registros de una tabla a tu php y después, cuando el usuario de click en el botón enviarlos via GET a otra pagina? o me podrías explicar de mejor forma ¿que es traer a un botón? ¿Ya probaste con un Array?

Comment: Ok tengo 3 tablas usuario, suscripcion y pagos, en la tabla pagos quiero guardar id_usuario y id_suscripcion cuando el usuario elige el plan de suscripcion mediante un botón q dice "pagar" (aquí ya comprobe que si se trae el id_plan porque es donde hago el while de la consulta q se trae todo de la tabla suscripcion), entonces retomo, cuando le da a ese botón pagar se le abre en la misma pantalla un formulario, ese formulario a su vez  le pide los datos del pago para guardarlos en la tabla pagos, lo q necesito es q mediante el botón "guardar pago" de ese formulario me guarde el id_suscripcion.

Comment: ok, cuando el usuario da click al "boton" pagar (plan de suscripción) ¿en que variable o en donde recibes el id_suscripcion? ¿o lo que necesitas es que te guarde id_suscripcion en 2 bd?

Comment: ¿Lo podrías ejemplificar con un array para simular como recibes los datos y como los observa el usuario?

Comment: Actualice la pregunta con el código para que se entienda mejor

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo haces con un input de tipo hidden?

Comment: ¿Exactamente en dónde iría el input hidden?

Comment: Al usar modal la variable `<?php echo $fila[0]; ?>` esta en la misma pagina. Si quieres "refrescar" la pagina la recibes con $_REQUEST o $_POST. en unos momentos te pongo un ejemplo.

Comment: Si la quieres enviar (guardar) la puedes poner en un `value="";`

Comment: Entiendo ¿pero en que parte del formulario Modal la recibo?, porque he intentado de todo y nada.

Comment: Si te funciona la respuesta, no olvides dar en la "palomita" del lado izquierdo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explicación**:

Para ejemplificarte estoy utilizando un ejercicio de "modal css" de "Devcode" y tu "diseño html" (el que pusiste en tu pregunta). Estoy haciendo un ciclo `for` simulando el `while` que obtienes de `mysql`. Como te comente, cuando utilizas modal, tus "variables" están en la misma pagina.

**Funcion**:

Estoy ocupando un `onClick="mifuncion(this.id);` para identificar que botón es el que selecciona el usuario (para saber el id del plan).

**Para visualizar**:

Para que lo puedas visualizar estoy ocupando un `alert(i);` y un `document.getElementById("registropago").innerHTML`.

**Para insertarlo**:

Solo debes recibir `name="enviarid"`en tu `action="insertarpago.php"`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <style>
    .modal-contenido {
      background-color: grey;
      width: 300px;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      margin: 20% auto;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .modal {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      pointer-events: none;
      transition: all 1s;
    }
    
    #miModal:target {
      opacity: 1;
      pointer-events: auto;
    }
  </style>

<?php
//$id_plan = array("id01", "id02", "id03"); 
//for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
//echo $id_plan[$i]; Esta era la simulacion de while para que lo pudieras visualizar sin conexion.

while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($traerplanes)){
echo $fila[id_plan];
?>
    <div class="col-md-5 order-details" style="width:380px">
      <div class="section-title text-center">
      </div>
      <div class="order-summary">
        <div class="order-col">
          <div><strong>DESCRIPCIÓN</strong></div>
          <div><strong>TOTAL</strong></div>
        </div>
        <div class="order-products">
          <div class="order-col">
            <div style="text-align:justify; font-size:12px">
              <?php echo $fila['descripcion'];?>
            </div>
            <div>$
              <?php echo $fila['precio'];?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="order-col">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="order-col">
          <div><strong>TOTAL</strong></div>
          <div><strong class="order-total" style="color:#069;">$<?php echo $fila['precio'];?></strong></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="text-align:center;">
        <label>
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
      </div>
      <a id="<?php echo $fila[id_plan]; ?>" href="#miModal" onClick="mifuncion(this.id);">Pagar</a>// aquí estaba la simulación del ciclo for que solo era para ejemplificar tu while echo $id_plan[$i];.

    </div>
    <?php } ?>


    <div id="miModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-contenido">

        <a href="#">X</a>
        <form action="insertarpago.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="registropago">Pagar Plan</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
              <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre del titular de la cuenta de donde pagó" id="nombre" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
              <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="apellido del titular de la cuenta de donde pagó" id="apellido" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="documento">Documento</label>
              <input type="text" name="documento" placeholder="cédula, rif o pasaporte del titular de la cuenta" id="documento" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="banco">Banco</label>
              <input type="text" name="banco" placeholder="nombre del banco desde donde pagó" id="banco" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="numero_cuenta">Número de cuenta</label>
              <input type="number" name="numero_cuenta" placeholder="número de cuenta desde donde pagó" id="numero_cuenta" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="referencia">Referencia</label>
              <input type="number" name="referencia" placeholder="número de referencia de la transferencia" id="referencia" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="monto">Monto</label>
              <input type="number" name="monto" placeholder="monto de la transferencia en Bs.S" id="monto" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="capture_pago">Capture de pago (Opcional)</label>
              <input type="file" name="capture_pago" id="capture_pago" class="form-control">

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <a id="idpago" name="enviarid">ID</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Pago</button>
              </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>

        <script>
          function mifuncion(unclick) {
            var i = unclick;
            alert(i);
            document.getElementById("registropago").innerHTML = "Aquí esta tu id (" + i + ") de Pago";
            document.getElementById("idpago").innerHTML = "Aquí esta tu id (" + i + ") para enviar";
          }
        </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115518/discussion-on-answer-by-abner-traer-id-con-un-boton-a-un-formulario-en-la-misma).